# How to retrieve the next and previous ids on a button click using Linq to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

In the steps from my json file, I want to construct a linq that moves to the next or previous id depending on whether you hit the back button (previous id) or the next button (next contentid). If this occurs, the label's text must be modified. I'm not sure how to accomplish that in Linq.

**This is my JSON where i need next or previous text based on contentid in steps**

```
{
  "protocols": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Pols meten",
      "steps": [
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Voorzorg",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "1",
              "text": "voor blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "2",
              "text": "voor blabla2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Handeling",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "3",
              "text": "handeling blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contens": [
            {
              "contentid": "4",
              "text": "handeling blabla2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Nazorg",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "5",
              "text": "nazorg blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "6",
              "text": "nazorg blabla2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "versie": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My json class**

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("protocols")]
        public List<Protocol> Protocols { get; set; }
    }
    public class Protocol
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("steps")]
        public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("versie")]
        public string Versie { get; set; }
    }
    public class Step
    {
        [JsonProperty("chapterTitle")]
        public string ChapterTitle { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("contents")]
        public List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    }
    public class Content
    {
        [JsonProperty("contentid")]
        public string Contentid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**And sit are my 2 buttons where I go to the next or previous id when I click on it if they exist**

```
        readonly Step _step;
        private Protocol protocol;
    public StepView(Step step, string nextTitle)
    {
        _step = step;
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = nextTitle;
        // krijg label text
        lblText.Text = step.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text != null).Text;
    }
      public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_step == null)
        {
            lblText.Text = _step.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text != null).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            var index = protocol.Steps.IndexOf(_step) + 1;
            _step = protocol.Steps.Count >= index ? protocol.Steps.LastOrDefault() : protocol.Steps[index];
        }

        lblText.Text = _step?.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text != null).Text;
    }

    public void BtnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //voor als het de allerlaatste stap is en je geen stap meer terug kan 
        if (_step == null)
        {
            _step = protocol.Steps.LastOrDefault();
        }
        //als je nog wel een stap terug kunt 
        else
        {
            var index = protocol.Steps.IndexOf(_step) - 1;
            _step = index >= 0 ? protocol.Steps[index] : protocol.Steps.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        lblText.Text = _step?.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text != null).Text;
    }
```

how can I make the buttons go after the previous text or the next one if there are any?

Comment: BtnClicked = true; if (BtnClicked) {....} what purpose of that code? If you want to keep track of current step you need at least to remove readonly from _step and change it when buttons clicked using index calculations.

Comment: can you give a example? @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: This boolean makes no sense, I dont think that user can push multiple buttons at time to worry about concurrency in this case. You should worry about proper null and range checking rather than multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce field `private Content content;`

Handlers:

```
public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = content == null ? 0 : _step.Contents.IndexOf(content) + 1;
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}

public void BtnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = content == null ? _step.Contents.Count - 1 : _step.Contents.IndexOf(content) - 1;
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting System.NullReferenceException: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at `var index = protocol.Steps.IndexOf(_step) - 1;`

Comment: what to change then?

Comment: and protocol is null

Comment: rootObject.Protocols.FirstOrDefault().Steps.ElementAtOrDefault(startingIndex -/+1)
will get index you want

Comment: can you give a code example with that @PowerMouse

Comment: How do you initialize `protocol` field?

Comment: Protocol protocol; @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: I changed my code in my question @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: the label text becomes empty on both buttons with your new code @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: content = null thats the issue what do i need to change

Comment: Edited code to support if `content` is uninitialized.

Comment: What he is doing with that code the first time you click is empty and then the next one is the first one.. I need to go to the next id text from the json @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: Append this line to constructor if you want first element to be selected after initialization `content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(0);`

Comment: if you look at my json i also have 3 chapters you can choose from. I use the name ChapterTitle for that. So there he starts with a different id. So what I want exactly is wherever you start it will go to the previous or next text based on the content id. And it hasn't worked yet @AlexeyRumyantsev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239037/discussion-between-teun-and-alexey-rumyantsev).

Answer (score 0):

as you requested. I made an example. you passing index of selected item and direction to pick next item such is previous or next
(you can remove where condition - i am going over the records contained title in this example)

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"protocols\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Pols meten\",\"steps\":[{\"chapterTitle\":\"Voorzorg\",\"contents\":[{\"contentid\":\"1\",\"text\":\"voor blabla\"}]},{\"contents\":[{\"contentid\":\"2\",\"text\":\"voor blabla2\"}]},{\"chapterTitle\":\"Handeling\",\"contents\":[{\"contentid\":\"3\",\"text\":\"handeling blabla\"}]},{\"contens\":[{\"contentid\":\"4\",\"text\":\"handeling blabla2\"}]},{\"chapterTitle\":\"Nazorg\",\"contents\":[{\"contentid\":\"5\",\"text\":\"nazorg blabla\"}]},{\"contents\":[{\"contentid\":\"6\",\"text\":\"nazorg blabla2\"}]}],\"versie\":\"1\"}]}";
    rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    
    rootObject.Dump();

    GetPrevNextItem(1,Direction.Up).Dump("Previous record");
    GetPrevNextItem(1,Direction.Down).Dump("Next Record");
    
}

public Step GetPrevNextItem(int startingIndex, Direction dir)
{
    if (dir == Direction.Up)
    return rootObject.Protocols.FirstOrDefault().Steps
                    .Where(ss=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss.ChapterTitle))
                    .ElementAtOrDefault(startingIndex -1);
    else
    return rootObject.Protocols.FirstOrDefault().Steps
                    .Where(ss=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss.ChapterTitle))
                    .ElementAtOrDefault(startingIndex +1);
}

public enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Down
}

public RootObject rootObject {get;set;}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("protocols")]
    public List<Protocol> Protocols { get; set; }
}
public class Protocol
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("steps")]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("versie")]
    public string Versie { get; set; }
}
public class Step
{
    [JsonProperty("chapterTitle")]
    public string ChapterTitle { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("contents")]
    public List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
public class Content
{
    [JsonProperty("contentid")]
    public string Contentid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

[image: results]